# Is it possible to return generic value while converting from string?

Tags: c#

I have a system that relays on third party SW that stores data elements.

The data elements in the storage, have DataType and Value properties to describe the underline data object. Each `DataElement` can be fetched by name from the storage. (like an external database)

```
public class DataElemenet
{
    public string Type { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

I want to create a BL object to abstract the `DataElement` specifics in the following manner:

```
public class DataGetter
{
    private readonly DataElement dataObject;
    public DataGetter(string name)
    {
        this.dataObject = <third_party>.GetObject(name);
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        if (this.dataObject.Type != "integer")
           throw new Exception();
        
        return int.Parse(this.dataObject.Value);
    }
}
```

Now, in the third party SW, `Type` can be a lot of different types (e.g., `List<int>`, `double`, `List<string>` ....)

As I can't overload the `GetValue` to return a different return value type, I tried a generic approach.

```
public T GetValue<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) != this.dataObject.Type)
       throw new Exception();
    
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(this.dataObject.Value, typeof(T));
}
```

while this approach will work, I wish to optimize it in a following way (handle all data types by case):
**EDIT**

As was mentioned in one of the comments, this approach works only for primitives, and can't support the conversion to `List<int>` for example. So I tried to use the following approach:

```
public T GetValue<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) != this.dataObject.Type)
       throw new Exception();

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
       return int.Parse(this.dataObject.Value);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
       return bool.Parse(this.dataObject.Value);
    ....

}
```

The compiler if complaining as it can't convert a `int` / `bool` (in the above cases) to `T`.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand the problem if you have a solution.  Asking for optimizations is asking for opinions and is off topic.

Comment: The whole point of a generic method is that you do the same thing for every type. If you have to using conditional statements to check the type and do something different for each one, you shouldn't be using generics in the first place.

Comment: Why do you think that would be an optimization compared to `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: You say that that first generic method will work but will it really? Have you tested it with all those different types you mentioned? The documentation for `Convert.ChangeType` says this: "For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the IConvertible interface, because the method simply wraps a call to an appropriate IConvertible method. The method requires that conversion of value to conversionType be supported". How can a `string` be converted to a `List<int>` under those conditions?

Comment: Note that caller must specify T in this case (cannot be inferred), so caller will have to do `GetValue<int>`, and even ugly things like `GetValue<List<string>>`. Even worse is that it can supply unsupported type. All that makes me think it's better to just do `GetInt`, `GetBool` etc methods.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: indeed this was anther reason i went to split the method to case by case. i agree i didn't mention this in the question itself

Comment: You can then also add `object Get()` which will convert the `Value` to the type `Type` and return as object. Basically this design will be the same as `SqlDataReader` has to read columns of database supplied row (it has `GetInt32` `GetBoolean` etc etc): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on the new `IParsable<T>` interface from .NET7 which has a generic static `Parse` method which you can use in generic contexts.

Keeping your original attempt in place, this could look something like:

```cs
public T GetValue<T>()
    where T : IParsable<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) != this.dataObject.Type)
       throw new Exception();
    
    return T.Parse(this.dataObject.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Notice that the type you pass now must implement the static abstract `Parse` method from `IParsable`, which the vast majority of standard primitive and basic types do. If you then want to support things such as arbitrary lists from a string, you can create your own custom collections that implement `IParsable` and put the conversion from string to list there.

The advantage of this approach is that it is truly polymorphic: it doesn't force you to check for all possible types in a gigantic switch statement. Thus it is vastly more maintainable and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible: you need to cast to `object` first (be aware of boxing/unboxing in that cases).

```
public T GetValue<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) != this.dataObject.Type)
       throw new Exception();

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
       return (T)(object)int.Parse(this.dataObject.Value);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
       return (T)(object)bool.Parse(this.dataObject.Value);
    ....

}
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Pfns6)